# Reactjs - Drag and Drop (react-dnd) troubleshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have reactjs test project coded like this.

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
    import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

    import Square from './Square';
    import Knight from './Knight';
    import { moveKnight } from './Game';
    import { canMoveKnight, moveKnight } from './Game';

    @DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
.....
```

But when I run code, I got following error.

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/Board.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (11:0)

   9 | import { canMoveKnight, moveKnight } from './Game';
  10 | 
> 11 | @DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
     | ^
  12 | 
  13 | export default class Board extends Component {
  14 |   static propTypes = {

 @ ./src/index.js 16:13-31
```

If you have rich experience about react-dnd and react-dnd-html5-backend, Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your decorators are not being processed by Babel (you're using Babel/Webpack, I'm assuming). You need to install the [babel-plugin-transform-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators) plugin, or [babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) if you need the old behavior.